# Recovering Linux files from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, ubuntu-9.04

I just installed Windows 7 RC and forgot to save a few important files that were in Ubuntu 9.04. I did not have Ubuntu installed on a separate partition. I just used the install inside Windows option. Is there anyway I can still recover my files?

Comment: Did you do a full install, or an upgrade to install Windows 7?

Comment: I did an upgrade.

Comment: No it was on the same disk. Under this folder: C:\Ubuntu

Comment: the folder is still there?

Comment: No I had to make room for Windows 7

Comment: Even if it were still there I never could access the .disk file. That file alone was the whole OS (it was about 7GB).

Comment: id say your pretty hosed then.  that 7GB file was your ubuntu partition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks as though you had Ubuntu installed so that it used a flat file (C:\ubuntu\ubuntu.disk) as its filesystem.

If it was still around, you could boot up Linux using a Live CD of Ubuntu, mount that image and then proceed to copy things from it without a problem.

But, you deleted it. The data is gone and probably unrecoverable since you said you deleted it to make room for other things.

Unless you had another .disk file sitting somewhere that Ubuntu was storing data on, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yep, that sucks, but at least Now You Know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have many chances to get it back, as the files certainly were overwritten... you can try something like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [Recuva](http://www.recuva.com/)